# ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que Spring caché no realice el cache si un parámetro es nulo o es igual a un valor?

Tags: java, spring, cache

Existe alguna forma en que Spring Caché no realice el caché si uno de los parámetros es nulo o igual a un valor?.

Tengo el siguiente método y quiero que no se realice el caché si category es nulo o es igual a 0.

```
    @Cacheable(value = "getValues", key = "#search + \"|\" + #category + \"|\" + #user.getId()")
    public List<String> getValues(String search, Integer category, User user) {
        return dao.getValues(search, category, user);
    }
```

Estoy usando Spring 3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde `Spring 3.2` existe `unless` que te te permite realizar lo que necesitas

```
@Cacheable(value = "getValues", key = "#search + \"|\" + #category + \"|\" + #user.getId()", unless="#category == null"))
public List<String> getValues(String search, Integer category, User user) {
    return dao.getValues(search, category, user);
}
```

El significado en español de `unless` es "a no ser que", entonces te refieres al campo que quieres condicionar, en este caso `category`.

La importancia de `unless` es que evalúa el valor antes de ejecutar la función.

[Unless](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#unless())

**EDICION**

Puedes ocupar `condition`, esto no guardara cache si es que la condicion no se cumple. En este caso lo hara solo si `category != null`

```
@Cacheable(value = "getValues", condition="#category != null", key = "#search + \"|\" + #category + \"|\" + #user.getId()"))
```

Y la diferencia con `unless` es que esto es evaluado despues de llamar al metodo.

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta. Estoy usando Spring 3.1.1

Comment: Ok! gracias.. por que no actualizas? voy a ver si te puedo ayudar con tu version

Comment: @d345k0 actualice si es que te sirve `condition`